# overflow:hidden on spans in an li doesn't work

Tags: css, html-lists, overflow

I'm building a new website and I want to make some effect when hovering on a `li`.

There are three `li` as you can see:

```
           <ul id="list">
               <li>HomePage</li>
               <li>About<span>Me</span></li>
               <li>Contact<span>Form</span></li>
           </ul>
```

I want to hide the "Page" from homepage, "Me" from AboutMe and "form" from ContactForm.
I'm going to use a little Jquery to make it, so when I hover the `li`, it will animate the width of the `li` and then show the `spans`.

The CSS code is:

```
#list li{
    font-size:14px;
    color:#3ea9c1;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:60px;
    display:inline;
    width:20px;
    padding:25px;
    transition:1s ease;
}
```

I actually don't want to use too much Jquery because I the css issue is bothering me.
Can't find out what's wrong here. Will be happy for help!
Thanks you.

Comment: You would be better off having it be empty and manage the content with javascript.

Comment: I don't see why would you need JQuery or `overflow` here. What's wrong with `visibility: hidden`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need Jquery you can animate the font-size of the spans.

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: 1s ease;
}
#list li {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #3ea9c1;
  height: 60px;
  display: inline;
  width: 20px;
  padding: 25px;
}
#list li:hover span {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>Home <span>Page</span>
  </li>
  <li>About <span>Me</span>
  </li>
  <li>Contact <span>Form</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well, it actully works but it's still bothering me why the overflow isn't working. what i did wrong. I think i will need the overflow sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Why use jQuery at all?  This is all CSS and should do exactly what you're after.

```css
#list li{
    font-size:14px;
    color:#3ea9c1;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:60px;
    display:inline;
    width:20px;
    padding:25px;
    transition:1s ease;
}

#list li span {
    max-width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    transition: max-width 1s;
}
#list li:hover span {
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
               <li>Home<span>Page</span></li>
               <li>About<span>Me</span></li>
               <li>Contact<span>Form</span></li>
           </ul>
```